# Get unique block of data from a file based of a string in the block

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file with below data:

```
WXR
FI WG0644/AN ***C-GVVH***
DT QXS MIA7 121942 M31A
-    01 WXRQ   0644/   CYUL/MUHG .C-GVVH
/TYP 1/STA MUHG/STA MKJS/STA CYUL
--------
WXR
FI WG0644/AN ***C-GVVH***
DT QXS MIA7 121945 M32A
-    01 WXRQ   0644/   CYUL/MUHG .C-GVVH
/TYP 1/STA MUHG/STA MKJS/STA CYUL
--------
WXR
FI WG9510/AN ***C-GQWM***
DT QXS SAV7 122027 M33A
-    01 WXRQ   9510/   CYHZ/     .C-GQWM
/TYP 1/STA CYHZ/STA     /STA
--------
WXR
FI WG9510/AN ***C-GQWM***
DT QXS SAV7 122027 M34A
-    01 WXRQ   9510/   CYHZ/     .C-GQWM
/TYP 3/STA CYHZ/STA     /STA
--------
WXR
FI WG0498/AN ***C-FAWC***
DT QXS ORF7 122126 M18A
-    01 WXRQ   0498/   MDPC/CYYZ .C-FAWC
/TYP 1/STA CYYZ/STA KPIT/STA
--------
```

I want to get the unique blocks which has unique ref number ( C-GVVH,C-GVVH,C-GQWM,C-FAWC).I am expecting output as below:

```
WXR
FI WG0644/AN ***C-GVVH***
DT QXS MIA7 121942 M31A
-    01 WXRQ   0644/   CYUL/MUHG .C-GVVH
/TYP 1/STA MUHG/STA MKJS/STA CYUL
--------
WXR
FI WG9510/AN ***C-GQWM***
DT QXS SAV7 122027 M33A
-    01 WXRQ   9510/   CYHZ/     .C-GQWM
/TYP 1/STA CYHZ/STA     /STA
--------
WXR
FI WG0498/AN ***C-FAWC***
DT QXS ORF7 122126 M18A
-    01 WXRQ   0498/   MDPC/CYYZ .C-FAWC
/TYP 1/STA CYYZ/STA KPIT/STA
--------
```

It would be better if its a single line command.Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you tried this far? It's usually considered a good practise to [put out some effort in terms of actual code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).